# Using the google-custom-search for educational purpose

Tags: google-custom-search

Is there any access to the "google-custom-search" for students?

It is for a thesis. I want to implement/use the "normalized google distance" for my dataset. Unfortunately, my university has no general agreement with google.

PS. yes I know I could simply parse the web-page. But it seems to be a bit lame if there is an api for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google discontinued the only paid option of the Custom Search Engine ([CSE](https://cse.google.ca/)), so now your only option is 'free' -- in return for seeing a few content-based ads in your custom search results.

The 'pro' option now is the json/atom Search [API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview), also free up to 100 queries per day.

I highly recommend that "anyone who ever uses a search engine", check them both out.  It takes minutes to create a custom search - and after that there are countless optional ways to customize or integrate with other (free) tools like [Analytics](https://analytics.google.com) or [Sheets](https://www.google.ca/sheets/about/)/Slides/Forms/etc.  If your CSE gets popular enough, *they'll* start paying *you*.

Google has a lot of '[products](https://developers.google.com/products/)' that many people aren't aware of (most with free options) that.

Side note, since you're a class - Microsoft has some pretty sweet deals for anyone student/teacher with an email address on a school domain ($1000's in free software.)